# Неопределённое поведение при создании локальной const ссылки на временный объект?

Tags: c++

Содержит ли следующий код UB ? Ссылки на локальные объекты при возврате протухают, но если их вернуть по `const` ссылке, то время их жизни продлевается, все возвраты сделаны по `const` ссылке (правда через `auto`), вроде всё должно быть нормально:

```
std::vector<int> Foo(int N = 10)
{
    std::vector<int> rv;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        rv.push_back(i + 10);
    }
    return rv;
}

int GetNumber()
{
    const auto &num = Foo().front();
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    int x = GetNumber();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

PS. Однако этот код иногда ведёт себя неадекватно (не совсем прямо этот, это я ужал всё в минимальный пример, у нас std::vector более сложных объектов, и там ещё в параллеле крутятся потоки, это всё повышает вероятность реального проявления UB).

Comment: @Harry , приглашаю

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , приглашаю

Comment: `int GetNumber()
{
    const auto &num = Foo().front();
    return num;
}` - здесь по сути нет ссылки на локальный объект *вовне*. Вы работаете со ссылкой на временный объект, но только внутри функции, и возвращаете из нее `int`, а не `const int&` - т.е. при выходе получается *копия значения*, находящегося по ссылке. А сам локальный объект после этого никого не интересует, и ссылки на него вне функции нет. Оптимизатор вполне может разобраться, например, что можно обойтись одним вектором, без копирования - но это не важно. *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: @Harry , именно) Пишите в ответ) Для меня оказалось новостью, стыд и позор -_- (справедливости ради - этот код написал не я, проблема жила не менее полугода и не проявлялась)

Comment: И зачем ссылаться на  обьект, когда эту ссыльку вы никогда не используете?... Конечно это UB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном примере ссылки вообще нигде не возвращаются, только значения. Но самое главное в том, что и никакого продления времени жизни тут тоже не происходит. т.е. ссылка `const auto &num = Foo().front();` протухает сразу после выполнения этого выражения так как она биндится не прямо ко временному объекту `std::vector<int>`, а к ссылке на первый элемент этого вектора. Соответственно при разыменовании этой ссылки в `return num;` имеет место Неопределенное Поведение.